# All Apps referencing an old partition

Tags: partitioning, windows-8

In order to add apps to the Windows 8 All Apps menu, you can add shortcuts to the "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs" folder.

I have installed Windows 8 on a new D:\ partition, however, my All Apps menu is taking apps from the "Start Menu\Programs" folder on C:.

**How can I change the reference to point to the folder on the correct D:\ partition,** and how can I fix any other references like this that may point to the old partition?

*(C:\ contains the old Windows 7 installation; I'm dual-booting.)*

Comment: If Windows 8 is on D:\, what exactly is on the C:\ drive?

Comment: @BryanDenny the old Windows 7 installation.

Comment: Are you dual booting or are you single booting and left the data on the c:\?

Comment: @Bryan dual booting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just worked out that the entire installation was corrupted.

I installed Win8 on a new partition called D:, however, my CD drive is also called D:. Presumably this led to the registry pointing to the wrong place.

Solution? Reinstall Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

Laplink offers an expensive [package](http://www.laplink.com/index.php/individuals/pcmover-for-windows-8/pcmover-professional-8) for moving Windows 7 apps into Windows 8.

Alternatively, you could uninstall and reinstall your apps. I don't recommend dragging & dropping them onto `D:\` as plenty of software configuration files will reference the old locations and break as a result.